# docker-compose initialize volume content on build

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose to start few machines with different services.

During the build phase docker-compose creates few files I would like to work on; at the moment I manually copy those files to a directory I share with the host after the build.

The directory contents are shared via volumes.

    `volumes:
      - "./prg:/prg"`

Perhaps I am missing the obvious, but there is a way to populate the shared directory content on the build phase so when I do `docker-compose up` the first time I can start editing the files in `prg`?

Comment: Try to add `VOLUME /dir_you_want_export` to your Dockerfile. Otherwise, you'll need to mount volumes in `up` phase, not `build`.